# Calculating number of edges from a degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Problem: Suppose a graph $G$ has degree sequence $25, 18, 18, 5, 2, 2$.
How many edges are there in $G$?

I am assuming since the definition of degrees of a vertex that each one of the 6 vertex's (since there are $6$ nums in the degree sequence) has $n$ edges(paths) ($n$ being one of the six numbers in the degree sequence). So would the total number of edges in this case be $25+18+18+5+2+2$?

I don't think this graph exists as a simple graph, but would have to be drawn with the three vertices having degrees of $18$, $18$, and $25$ have loops or multiple edges between them. Do those count in the total number of edges?

Comment: I don't see how that degree sequence would work either.  However, you're forgetting that each edge connects 2 vertices.

Comment: This is perfectly fine for a graph in which repeated edges are allowed.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** For a vertex $v$, the degree of $v$ is the number of edges incident to $v$.
Counting the total degree, you will actually count each edge $\{u,v\}$ twice -- once when you count the degree of $u$, and once when you count the degree of $v$.

So, how should the total degree and the total number of edges be related?

If each edge $\{u,v\}$ gets counted for both $u$ and for $v$, then it has been counted twice -- and so the total degree is just twice the number of edges!

(This works if we allow multiple edges... it works with loops as well, with the convention that a loop on vertex $v$ contributes two to its total degree.)

So, if you notice that your total degree is 70, it must be the case that there are 35 edges.

Comment: so would it be (25+18+18+5+2+2) - (however many edges are shared between those 6 vertices)?

Comment: I tried drawing the graph, starting with the three vertices with degree sequence (5,2,2) and then drew the other three vertices with as many paths as I could while maintaining that the first three vertices had the degree sequence of (5,2,2). I have counted 9 edges being shared between all 6 vertices now. So now the only way to get the later three vertices to match the degree sequence of (25,18,18) I have to draw loops/multiple edges between those three. So is it the answer (9 + however many multiple edges/loops I draw next)? Im not sure how total degree and total edges are related

Comment: You're making it way too complicated!  Let me try again.

Answer (score 3):

it would be sum of degrees divided by two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is the sum of the sequence divided by two. Each edge is incident on two vertices. I have this same problem due tomorrow too. This link supports my idea http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DegreeSequence.html

Comment: but then again I could be wrong because that's including the loops (which I don't think are supposed to be counted twice)

Comment: and, commenting again. The graph in the problem could very well be a multigraph. It never said anything about being a complete graph.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the number of edges from the following observations:

- The degree of a vertex $v$ counts the number of times $v$ appears as the endpoint of an edge.
- If we sum the degrees, we get the total number of times any vertex appears as the endpoint of an edge.
- Each edge has two endpoints.

These observations will lead you to the result known as the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

This particular degree sequence obviously cannot be realized by a simple graph: the vertex of degree $25$ would have $25$ distinct neighbours, but there are only $6$ vertices.

It can be realized as a multigraph, however, as the following picture indicates:

[image: Multigraph]

In this figure, numbers on edges indicate their multiplicity.